# After adding one more table, columns multipy among themselves

Tags: mysql

I want to add one more table to my query which works good. But problem occurs after adding that table, and I could not figure it out why is that happening.

Query that works good

```
SELECT a.ArtId, a.ArtSifra, a.ArtNaziv,a.ArtRoditelj, a.ArtStanjeSA, a.ArtKategorija, a.ArtMjera, sum(b.artpaletatrenutnostanje) as palete, 
(a.artstanjesa + sum(b.artpaletatrenutnostanje)) AS ukupno,c.JmOznaka  
FROM artikli a 
JOIN artikli_palete_ulaz b on a.ArtID = b.ArtPaletaArtikal 
JOIN jedmj c ON a.ArtMjera = c.JmId  
WHERE a.ArtRoditelj != 0 AND a.ArtAktivan != 0 
GROUP BY a.ArtId  
ORDER BY a.ArtId ASC
```

Query 2 does not show good results

```
SELECT a.ArtId, a.ArtSifra, a.ArtNaziv,a.ArtRoditelj, a.ArtStanjeSA, a.ArtKategorija, a.ArtMjera, sum(b.artpaletatrenutnostanje) as palete, 
(a.artstanjesa + sum(b.artpaletatrenutnostanje)) AS ukupno,c.JmOznaka, sum(d.Izlaz) as promet  
FROM artikli a 
JOIN artikli_palete_ulaz b on a.ArtID = b.ArtPaletaArtikal 
JOIN jedmj c ON a.ArtMjera = c.JmId  
JOIN kartica_artikla_2015 d ON a.ArtId = d.Artikal
WHERE a.ArtRoditelj != 0 AND a.ArtAktivan != 0 AND d.VrstaDokumenta != 18
GROUP BY a.ArtId  
ORDER BY a.ArtId ASC
```

In Query 2, as could be seen on the code above I have added table kartica_artikla_2015. After adding that table, columns "palete" and "ukupno" shows not good results they multiply. Column "promet" does not give good result as well.

I was wondering what could cause this problem, and if someone has any suggestion how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It probably happens because there are more than one values in kartica_artikla_2015.Artikal for one artikli.ArtId.
One way of solving this problem in your case is using `EXISTS`.
So, instead of

```
JOIN kartica_artikla_2015 d ON a.ArtId = d.Artikal
WHERE a.ArtRoditelj != 0 AND a.ArtAktivan != 0 AND d.VrstaDokumenta != 18
```

try

```
WHERE a.ArtRoditelj != 0 AND a.ArtAktivan != 0 AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM kartica_artikla_2015 d
  WHERE a.ArtId = d.Artikal AND d.VrstaDokumenta != 18
)
```

**Edit:** I just noticed that you are also selecting a column from kartica_artikla_2015. With my solution, because you are not joining that table anymore, you need another approach. For example, instead of `sum(d.Izlaz) as promet` you could use `(SELECT SUM(d.Izlaz) FROM kartica_artikla_2015 d WHERE a.ArtId = d.Artikal) as promet`